# "System error: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple" when using cv2.blur

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I am just trying to apply a filter to an image using cv2, the opencv python bindings. Here is what my code look like:

```
im = cv2.imread('./test_imgs/zzzyj.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Image', cv2.blur(im, 2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It's almost copy-and-paste from the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20blur%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20ksize,%20Point%20anchor,%20int%20borderType%29). However, it just doesn't work, with no more trace than this message:

```
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

The same error occurs with GaussianBlur, but not with medianBlur. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For cv2.blur, you need to give ksize as a tuple of two elements , like (2,2). But for medianBlur, ksize = 3 is sufficient. It will deduct a square kernel from it.

So make code like this :

```
im = cv2.imread('./test_imgs/zzzyj.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Image', cv2.blur(im, (3,3)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hope it will work!!!

Comment: (2,2) does not work it needs to be something that divides modulo 1

Comment: @ThomasWeller Doesn't everything divide modulo 1?

Comment: Nvm I know now what you mean. `(2,2)` worked for `blur`, but for `GaussianBlur` there is an assertion `ksize.width%2==1`

Answer (score 16):

I have got the same issue when **upgrading Pillow** from `2.8.1` to `4.1.0`.

Here is a piece of example code that will generate the exception when running `Pillow==4.1.0`:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.new('RGBA', [100,100])
# An empty mask is created to later overlay the original image (img)
mask = Image.new('L', img.size, 255)
# Get transparency (mask) layer pixels, they will be changed!
data = mask.load()
# The function used later
def foo(x,y): return round(1.0*x/(y+1))
# Update all pixels in the mask according to some function (foo)
for x in range(img.size[0]):
    for y in range(img.size[1]):
        data[x,y] = foo(x,y)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 12, in <module>
    data[x,y] = foo(x,y)
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

The actual error here has **nothing** to do with what is stated in the exception. It is actually the type of the data assigned to data that is wrong. In `2.8.1` both `int` and `float` are valid, so things like `data[x,y]=1.0` is valid, while in `4.1.0` you **need** to use integers like any of this:

```
data[x,y]=1
data[x,y]=int(1.0)
```

So in the example above `foo` could be redefined to the following to work in both `2.8.1` and `4.1.0`.:

```
def foo(x,y): return int(round(1.0*x/(y+1)))
```

Comment: Yep, one of the most misleading error messages I've seen - pretty frustrating.