# SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple?

Tags: python, opencv

What causes the SystemError in this line of code
`cv2.line(output, point1, point2, (0,0,255), 5)`?

Comment: Sounds like the same problem as ["System error: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple" when using cv2.blur](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13225525). Are `point1` and `point2` tuples?

Comment: could you post the full error in the question?

Comment: Post full code as well to see what those variables are.

Answer (score 27):

Faced with the same problem and solved it by using tuples instead of lists:

```
# How it looked before:
point1, point2 = [x1, y1], [x2, y2]

# How it should be:
point1, point2 = (x1, y1), (x2, y2)
```

Comment: Facing the same issue and tried your solution but no luck.

Answer (score 12):

Python OpenCV drawing functions take points as tuples. Possibly your `point1` and `point2` are of some other type, eg. a `list` maybe. So try this

```
cv2.line(output, tuple(point1), tuple(point2), (0,0,255),5)
```

The error is raised, because the OpenCV Python extensions call the function [`PyArg_ParseTuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html) with something that is not a tuple. [[see here]](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-January/147091.html)

Answer (score 3):

It seems the lastest version opencv-python have fixed this issue, I upgrade opencv-python from 4.4.0.44 to 4.5.5.64 by `pip install --upgrade opencv-python`, then this error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
point1=(x1,x2)
point2=(y1,y2)
new_img=cv2.line(img,point1,point2,(0,0,255),3)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The passing arguments aren't matching with the desirable arguments. I have faced same problem for:

```
x = cv2.resize(img, (32*32)).flatten()
x.resize(3032, 1)
```

And, solve it by correcting 32*32 to 32, 32.

```
x = cv2.resize(img, (32,32)).flatten()
x.resize(3032, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

just write this following way
v2.line(output, tuple(point1), tuple(point2), (0,0,255), 5)?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

since it didn't work in colab :(with same error )

cv2.drawChessboardCorners(imgBoard, board_size, found_corners, True)
plt.imshow("imgBoard", imgBoard)

```
*i switched to my own small function:*
def showImageWithCorners(img,cornerToShow):
  plt.plot(cornerToShow[:,0], cornerToShow[:,1], marker='o', color="red")
  plt.imshow(img)
```