# Delaunay Triangulation using Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, triangulation, delaunay

I am trying to do the  Delaunay Triangulation using Python 3.5.2 and OpenCV 3.1. I am trying to use the function `cv2.cv2.Subdiv2D(rect)` but I am not able to add a point to the Subdiv object. What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

point = np.array([[1, 1]])
rect = (0, 0, 10, 10)

# Create an instance of Subdiv2D
subdiv = cv2.Subdiv2D(rect[0])
subdiv.insert(point)
```

It is throwing this message:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype)) in copyTo, file /Users/jenkins/miniconda/1/x64/conda-bld/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/copy.cpp, line 257

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/jenkins/miniconda/1/x64/conda-bld/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/copy.cpp:257: error: (-215) channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype) in function copyTo

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Comment: The same problem (ie, that for cv it must be a tuple and not a list) is discussed here. Proposed solutions are the same. [SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673359/systemerror-new-style-getargs-format-but-argument-is-not-a-tuple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong but shouldn't it be: `point = np.array([[1, 1]])`? The way you are doing you are declaring an array with values 1 and 1, not an array of points.

**Edit:**

Try using points as tuples:

```
points_list = []
points_list.append((1,1))
```

Source: http://www.learnopencv.com/delaunay-triangulation-and-voronoi-diagram-using-opencv-c-python/

Comment: there is no difference if I have just one point in the array, but your approach is better so I edited my question. But it is not solving my problem

Comment: Thank you !! Its finally working. How did you get this idea? I always thought that only difference between tuples and lists is that lists are dynamic.

Comment: I find the python documentation of opencv a bit lacking so I tested it myself. List are dynamic, you are right about that. However, note that my solution is actually using tuples as **2D points** inside a list called **point**. You can add more points to the list **point**. I'll edit to be clear.

Comment: Thank you! I had to explicitly cast the values in the tuple to `int`s. `subdiv.insert(pts.astype(np.int16))` also worked for me. However, only `pts.astype(np.int16)` worked - at least on my system, `int`, `np.int32`, `np.int64`, etc. didn't work. I'm not sure why...