# Python error: SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to run this code (which I didn't do) but it throws me this error and I have no idea, any suggestions?

```
inFloor = np.array([cv.pointPolygonTest(floorPoly_m, pt, False) for pt in self.xyz[:,:2]]) >= 0
```

error: SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

apparently the error is in the first argument of the pointPolygonTest function but that argument is this array,

[[7.177778 1.4777777]

[6.711111 1.7333333]

[6.388889 1.2333333]

[6.8444443 0.62222224]]

I tried to convert it to tuple but this function only accepts array .. it is very confusing for me

The complete error output is here:

```
 File "/home/rsc/Desktop/GUI1_b/install/livox_detection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/livox_detection/pointCloudLib.py", line 419, in topView_measure
    inFloor = np.array([cv.pointPolygonTest(floorPoly_m, pt, False) for pt in self.xyz[:,:2]]) >= 0
  File "/home/rsc/Desktop/GUI1_b/install/livox_detection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/livox_detection/pointCloudLib.py", line 419, in <listcomp>
    inFloor = np.array([cv.pointPolygonTest(floorPoly_m, pt, False) for pt in self.xyz[:,:2]]) >= 0
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

Comment: Please show the complete error traceback.

Comment: Try fix your problem, using examples from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673359/systemerror-new-style-getargs-format-but-argument-is-not-a-tuple

Comment: yes i tried... search the forum before asking the question here

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating opencv library with:

```
pip3 install opencv-python --upgrade
```