# most cv2 tuple arguments don't work in python 3.5 (windows 7)

Tags: opencv, tuples, python-3.5

I switched a project over from python 2.7 to 3.5 and now I can't use most functions that require tuples.

As an example:

```
rgb = (255,0,0)
cv2.circle(img,(x, y),2,rgb,-1)
```

will return the "new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple" system error.

No matter how I enter the tuple expressing the color of the circle it will always fail, even if I explicitly use "tuple()"

I realize this problem isn't new but the solutions available are package dependent (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-January/147091.html).

I just want to put dots on an image without having to bring in another library when the same script is already using opencv.

EDIT: it's complaining about the x,y. The reason this worked in 2.7 and not 3.5 are unclear but specifically declaring the value as a tuple() fixes the issue

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225525/system-error-new-style-getargs-format-but-argument-is-not-a-tuple-when-using
Your issue could also be related to Pillow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.5, the following works:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


img = np.zeros((100, 100))  # Black image
rgb = (255, 0, 0)
cv2.circle(img, (50, 50), 2, rgb, -1)  # Plot centered on (50, 50)
```

Could you try this on your system and see if the error persist?

(Using Windows 10, Anaconda3, OpenCV 3.1.0)

If this works, your issue may be related to the type of your variable 'img' or the type of its values (see the link I posted as a comment of your question)

Comment: you're correct, the tuple being rejected is my x,y not the rgb.  thank you