# Compiling with sage occurs "SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple"

Tags: python-2.7, runtime-error, ubuntu-16.04, sage

When the following codes are compiling with python everything is good, there is no error, but when I compile with sage it occurs the error : "SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple"
  Here is my code

```
from PIL import Image
file=Image.open('/home/mks/Desktop/Shamir_VSIS/si.jpeg')
file2=file.convert("L")
pix = file2.load()
colsize,rowsize=file2.size
for i in range(rowsize):
    for j in range(colsize):
        if pix[j,i]>250:
            pix[j,i]=250
file2.save('/home/mks/Desktop/Shamir_VSIS/si.pgm')
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["System error: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple" when using cv2.blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225525/system-error-new-style-getargs-format-but-argument-is-not-a-tuple-when-using)

Comment: See specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43656642/982257

Also, the pixels loaded from an image with PIL should in a numpy array, so you should use vectorized array operations, not `for` loops.  E.g. `pix[pix > 250] = 250` or simply use [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)